# Форма оплаты и проверки

Tags: php

Есть форма с проверкой на правильность заполнения и есть форма оплаты Liqpay. Нужно объединить их. Условие таково: Если нажата кнопка "Купить", то идет проверка формы на правильность заполнения, после чего нужно перейти на страницу оплаты Liqpay.

```
<? session_start();?>
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(trim($_POST['contact_email']) == '' or !eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['contact_email']))){
$hasError = true;
} else {
$email = trim($_POST['contact_email']);
}
if(!isset($hasError))  {

}
else {

}
die(header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>123</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="abcd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="email" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" value="" required>
<input class="buy_button" type="submit" value="Buy" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

И liqpay форма

```
<?
$private_key = "123456789";
$public_key = "i12345678";
$json_string = json_encode(
array(
"version" => "3",
"public_key" => $public_key,
"amount" => 50,
"currency" => "USD",
"description" => "test",
"type" => "buy",
"order_id" => date("d/m/Y-H:i:s"),
"language" => "en",
"paytypes" => "card",
"sandbox" => "1"
)
);
$data = base64_encode( $json_string );

$signature = base64_encode( sha1(
$private_key .
$data .
$private_key
, 1 ));
?>
<form method="POST" action="https://www.liqpay.ua/api/checkout" 
accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<? echo $data; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<? echo $signature; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" width="10" height="5" value="Buy" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: код?  проверка где? на клиенте, на сервере? или и там и там?  код, верстка.

Comment: я исправил вопрос